# Can we have a controversy tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think a tag to indicate that the OP is touching on a sensitive topic that is considered by most to be rather controversial in nature, it serves as a warning so that readers can choose to avoid entirely if it triggers them somehow when reading it. Or is there a similar tag already which serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 7):

First and usual question when talking about tags: what does it mean to be an expert in controversy?

And a more philosophical question: what does it make a topic controversial? Because I have seen heated comments on topics which I would have normally imagined animated like the club meeting of the geologist in the Big Bang Theory.

Other stacks have a "controversial topic" notice, which can be used to narrow down the comments. What you propose can be already achieved by ignoring tags, for example who doesn't like torture question can simply ignore that tag.

Comment: In fact, I've participated in heated discussions where, looking back months later, I was forced to ask myself, "why on earth did I waste that much of my time?" Controversy is not just in the eye of the beholder - it depends on the phase of the moon, the time of day, the existence of better-than-average creme soda, and whether or not I recently watched the News.